# Building a clock with 4 7 segment

Tags: arduino, clock

I am building a clock with 4 7 segment. I am successful in it and storing time using buttons, but when I go to the first segment I want it to blink and then the second one, third one, and fourth one.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no question is being asked and lacks details and code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

a snippet with blinking hour or minute part from [my clock project](https://github.com/JAndrassy/KitchenTimerClock/blob/master/KitchenTimerClock/KitchenTimerClock.ino) where the time is set first hours then minutes, not per digit:

```
 if (state == SET_HOUR || state == SET_MINUTE) {
    if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= SET_TIME_BLINK_MILLIS) {
      previousMillis = currentMillis;
      blink = !blink;
      if (state == SET_HOUR) {
        showClock(true, blink, true);
      } else {
        showClock(true, true, blink);
      }
    }
  }
```

prototype of the showClock function is

```
void showClock(bool showColon, bool showHour, bool showMinute);
```

my SET_TIME_BLINK_MILLIS  is 250 milliseconds